# Will Quantaray QTB 7500A with module CN AF work with Canon Rebel XSi?

Tags: flash, canon-450d

I saw your earlier post about a new module that was required for use with the quantaray QTB7500A with the canon rebel xsi?  I'm not sure what you meant by new module...my module says CN AF and has 1/16 full and TTL modes...none of these seem to work.  The camera says it doesn't recognize the external flash.

---

Thank you for such detailed information...I do have an off-camera flash cord that I will probably have to use until I can find the new module...You are the best!

Comment: This does not appear to be a question. Who's "earlier post"? If this was intended to be a comment on another question, please post it as a comment on that question.

Comment: yes, sorry...my question is I have a quantaray QTB 7500A with it says module CN AF with manual and TTL auto settings...it doesn't seem to be recognizing my canon rebel xsi camera?  says it doesn't recognize external flash...can I get a new module to go with QTB 7500A?

Comment: I think she was refering to a question I'd asked at http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2124/105

Answer (score 2):

No it won't work, not without an updated module.
In order for companies like Quantaray (it's actually rebadged Sigma) to produce flash guns cheaply, they've separated the flash from the electronics that interface with the camera. This separated component is what I am referring to when I say an updated "module." Along with producing a standard flashgun that works with a variety of camera systems, Sigma is able to update the electronics as Canon changes them. Canon's E-TTL system is proprietary and as such, Sigma has to reverse engineer the flash interface).

Canon has updated their flash hotshoe interface so it is no longer compatible with older thirdparty flashguns. In order to make use of your flash, you will either need to use it in manual mode with a off-camera flash cord, or find an updated flash module (when I last checked this wasn't easy to find). I have the same exact problem with the Sigma DG500 Super and my 5D Mark II. My 5d2 cannot trigger the Sigma as is. I will have to send it to Sigma and have it rechipped